# How to allow recursion for only 1 zone?

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Is it possible to allow recursion for a single zone in BIND 9.6?

Comment: Don't you mean 'view'?

Comment: I don't think so, I've created a zone which redirects any queries for www.mydomain.com to another name server and anything else is resolved locally. This redirect only works if recursion is enabled in named.conf.options, but has the adverse affect of allowing any domain to be resolved by the server such as google.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, type forward. See [How to configure a name server to forward some queries to other name servers](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/194-how-to-configure-a-name-server-to-forward-some-queries-to-other-name-servers/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more complete answer I was looking for.  Adapted from *DNS Cookbook*.

Use a zone statement of type forward to tell a BIND name server to forward queries for domain names that end in the specified suffix to particular name servers. For example:

```
zone "bar.example" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 10.0.0.9; };
};
```

This tells the name server to forward queries for domain names that end in bar.example to the name server at 10.0.0.9.